# How check that the Oracle Database is up?

Tags: oracle

For our application we have a configuration file for connecting to the Oracle database (URL, username, password).

The application takes 2-5 minutes to start.  If there is something wrong with database I see this in logs, but I have to wait 2-5 minutes. This is a lot of time.

So I want to find out **quickly and simply** a way to determine that the database is all OK and online.

Do you have any idea how I might do it ?

Answer (score 31):

If you run the following query:

```
SELECT INSTANCE_NAME, STATUS, DATABASE_STATUS FROM V$INSTANCE;
```

It should return:

```
INSTANCE_NAME    STATUS       DATABASE_STATUS
---------------- ------------ -----------------
YOUR_DBASE       OPEN         ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 13):

`ps -ef | grep pmon`

PMON (process monitor) process checks all other background processes. Then you must check database's `alert_<SID>.log` for further investigation.

check in different operating systems and gets os user.

```
  SCRIPT=${0##*/}

  sid="ORCL"
  PMON_PROCESS="ora_pmon_${sid}"

  echo "Definition Oracle Pmon_Prozess:  ${PMON_PROCESS}"

  pid=$( UNIX95=TRUE ps -eo pid,args | awk '( ($NF == "'${PMON_PROCESS}'" ) && ($1 != mypid) ){ print $1 }' mypid=$$ )
  
  if [ "X${pid}" = "X" ]; then
    echo "${SCRIPT}: Database \"${v_sid}\" (pid=${pid}) not started."
    exit 1
  else
    ORA_RUN_RELEASE=$( UNIX95=TRUE ps -eo pid,user,args | awk '( ($NF == "'${PMON_PROCESS}'" ) && ($1 != mypid) ){ print $2 }' mypid=$$ )
  fi
```

Or Python version (inspired by [Tanel Poder's findhomes.sh](https://tanelpoder.com/2011/02/28/finding-oracle-homes-with/))

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import glob
# Emulate trick form tanelpoder
# https://tanelpoder.com/2011/02/28/finding-oracle-homes-with/
#
# printf "%6s %-20s %-80s\n" "PID" "NAME" "ORACLE_HOME"
# pgrep -lf _pmon_ |
#  while read pid pname  y ; do
#    printf "%6s %-20s %-80s\n" $pid $pname `ls -l /proc/$pid/exe | awk -F'>' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/bin\/oracle$//' | sort | uniq`
#  done
#
# It s basically looking up all PMON process IDs and then using /proc/PID/exe link to find out where is the oracle binary of a running process located
#
for cmd_line_file in glob.glob('/proc/[0-9]*/cmdline'):
    try:
        with open(cmd_line_file) as x:
            cmd_line = x.read().rstrip("\x00")
            if not cmd_line.startswith('ora_pmon_'):
                continue
            _, _, SID = cmd_line.split('_')
            #
            piddir = os.path.dirname(cmd_line_file)
            exefile = os.path.join(piddir, 'exe')
            inode = os.stat(exefile)
            #
            if not os.path.islink(exefile):
                continue
            oraclefile = os.readlink(exefile)
            ORACLE_HOME = os.path.dirname(oraclefile)
            ORACLE_HOME = os.path.dirname(ORACLE_HOME)
            print("{sid:20s} {home}".format(sid=SID, home=ORACLE_HOME))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        #print("Missing file ignored: {}".format(cmd_line_file)) # process exited quickly
        pass
```

Comment: it seems there was an easier solution : https://serverfault.com/questions/38488/how-can-i-tell-if-an-oracle-database-is-mounted-and-activated

Answer (score 6):

First thing first: you need to know the username and password to connect to database for step 2

1. Check the oracle process runs:

   On Un*x:

   ```
   ps -ef|grep pmon
   ```

   On Windows:

   ```
   tasklist|findstr /i oracle
   ```

   if the command in any case returns output i.e. if the pmon/oracle process is running in your environment the database is running.
2. Go to `ORACLE_HOME/bin` and run:

   ```
    ./sqlplus /nolog
   ```

   If after login you get errors, then the database does not run:

   ```
   SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Feb 31 21:61:61 2014
   Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
   Enter user-name: oracle
   Enter password: 
   ERROR:
   ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
   ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
   Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
   Process ID: 0
   Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
   ```

Comment: on windows start of sqlplus would be sqlplus /nolog

Comment: What's with "Un*x"? What are the variants?

Answer (score 3):

You should use/write a script that will connect to the server and see if your database is online. Here the Oracle guys will help. Just execute it from a batch/shell script (see [Running Scripts From SQL Command Line](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#CJAGIECA)) and see it's output. If everything is alright than you have your answer.

Or just try with SQL*Plus client.

Answer (score 0):

It might be wise to run an actual query against the database as well.  This just ensures that you can both connect and query.  I would make it something very simple and fast, such as:

```
SELECT pk_column 
  FROM sometable
WHERE rownum <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

PMON will check all the bg processes

```
ps -ef|grep pmon
```

In addition, we can check the database is running or not.

```
ps -ef|grep mydb
```

Answer (score 0):

To check general database status, I recommend:

1. Check if database processes are running. For example, from a Unix shell, running:

   ```
   $ ps -ef | grep pmon
   ```

   will show the running databases, startup times, and which Oracle users started each one.
2. Check if listeners are running using `$ ps -ef | grep tns` and `$ lsnrctl status LISTENER`
3. Selecting `gv$resource_limit` will show if database reached some configured limit.
4. To check if there were any database errors, you should check `alert.log`.

For more details see [my blog post](https://bbdd-error.blogspot.co.nz/2017/09/check-general-database-status.html).